# Make longer std::array accessible as if it's shorter

Tags: c++, stdarray

I am implementing my static multi-dimentional vector class. I am using `std::array` as the underlying data type.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Vector {
    private:
    std::array<T, N> data;
};
```

I want to make my class downwards-compatible, so I am writing this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Vector : public Vector<T, N-1>{
    private:
    std::array<T, N> data;
};

template <typename T>
class Vector<T, 0> {};
```

My goal is that when one instance is used in downwards-compatible mode, its underlying data should be able to be reliably accessed:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
T& Vector<T, N>::operator[](int i) {
    // Do boundary checking here
    return this->data[i];
}

void foo(Vector<int, 3>& arg) {
    arg[1] = 10;
}

Vector<int, 5> b;
foo(b);
// Now b[1] should be 10
```

There are two points here:

- `Vector<T, 5>` should be accepted by `foo()`, `Vector<T, 2>` should be rejected.
- Changes to `b[0]` through `b[2]` in `foo()` should pertain. `b[3]` and `b[4]` should not be accessible in `foo()`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: That's a rather poor design. If `N` is 10, you end up creating 10 `std::array` objects, with sizes 10, 9, ..., 1.

Comment: @RSahu That's not what I want but I can't find a way.

Comment: I don't think this is a good design. In addition to R Sahu's point, what would `arg.size()` return in `foo`? `3`? `5`? A better design might be one that uses "slices", e.g. non-owning portions of a potentially larger array.

Comment: I think you want a two-stage process. A storage class, and an accessor wrapper (think std::string_view).

Comment: To make functions accept or reject different template classes can't you use `enable_if` on the array `.size()`? Doing it through recursive, redundant inheritance definitely smells and probably won't work anyway.

Comment: Consider making a proxy type that acts as a view on 'Vector' and making that view down compatible instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simple read wrapper around `std::array<>` itself?

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct ArrayReader {
public:
  // Intentionally implicit.
  template<std::size_t SRC_LEN>
  ArrayReader(std::array<T, SRC_LEN> const& src) 
  : data_(src.data()) {
    static_assert(SRC_LEN >= N);
  }
private:
  T const* data_;
};

void foo(ArrayReader<float, 3>);
void bar() {
    std::array<float, 4> a;
    std::array<float, 2> b;

    foo(a);
    foo(b); //BOOM!
}
```

Of course, you can easily substitute `std::array` for your own type, this is just an example of the principle.

Answer (score 0):

Have `array` keep the data, and then create additional non-owning class, e.g. `array_view` that will keep only a pointer. It will have generic constructor that accepts the array, and will have a `static_assert` to check the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this:

```
template <class Container, std::size_t size>
struct range_view
{
  range_view(Container * p): container(p) { assert(size <= p->size()); }
  auto & operator[](std::size_t i) { return (*container)[i]; }
 private:
  Container * container;
};
```

Then you simply define `foo` as:

```
template <class C>
void foo(range_view<C, 3> c)
{
  c[1] = 1;
}
```

Comment: OP wants a compile-time check.

Comment: @Frank I don't see that stated anywhere in the question or comments

Comment: Their implementation goes through a lot of template hoop jumping that wouldn't be necessary otherwise. Also, "should be rejected" really implies a compile-time check.

Comment: @Frank fair enough, but I think the runtime check is fine for practical purposes. In a more complete implementation you could determine whether or not you can check at compile time and then decide when you can check at compile time or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that is closest to what I think you would need.

Make `Vector` a viewer/user of the data, not the owner of the data.

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t I>
class Vector : public Vector<T, N, I-1>
{
   public:
      Vector(std::array<T, N>& arr) : Vector<T, N, I-1>(arr), arr_(arr) {}

      T& operator[](int i) {
         return arr_[i];
      }

   private:
      std::array<T, N>& arr_;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Vector<T, N, 0ul>
{
   public:
      Vector(std::array<T, N>& arr) : arr_(arr) {}
   private:
      std::array<T, N>& arr_;
};

void foo(Vector<int, 5, 3>& arg) {
    arg[1] = 10;

    // Can't find a way to make this a compile time error.
    arg[3] = 10;
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::array<int, 5> arr;
   Vector<int, 5, 5> b(arr);
   foo(b);
   std::cout << b[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration of how to implement the `Vector` class that you tried in your question. At each level you only store 1 value instead of an array and that way when you compose all your `N` `Array`s together you get space for `N` values. Of course then calling `operator[]` gets tricky, which is the meat of what I wanted to demonstrate.

```
#include <utility>

template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct Array : Array<T, N-1>
{
    T & operator[](std::size_t i)
    {
        return const_cast<T&>((*const_cast<const Array*>(this))[i]);
    }

    const T & operator[](std::size_t i) const
    {
        return Get(i, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    }

    template <std::size_t i>
    const T & Geti() const
    {
        return static_cast<const Array<T, i+1>&>(*this).GetValue();
    }

    const T & GetValue() const { return value; }

    template <std::size_t ... indices>
    const T & Get(std::size_t i, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, indices...>) const
    {
        using X = decltype(&Array::Geti<0>);
        X getters[] = { &Array::Geti<indices>... };
        return (this->*getters[i])();
    }

    template <std::size_t i, class = typename std::enable_if<(i <= N)>::type>
    operator Array<T, i>&() { return (Array<T, i>&)*this; }
private:
    T value;
};

template <class T>
struct Array<T, 0>{};

void foo(Array<float, 3> & a) { a[1] = 10; }

int main()
{
    Array<float, 10> a;
    foo(a);
}
```